# App crashing while disabling App location

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service ongoing which takes current location and sends it to the server.
While App is in the background with Service on, if I go to settings and turn off my App Location, the app is crashing I'm unable to able to catch the crash. 
But if I kill the app and re-run it again the crash does not happen at that time.
It only happens when the app is in the background and at the same time app location permission is turned off.

Thanks & Regards
Syed

Comment: Share us your piece of code which is throwing error

Comment: Sir error is not displaying that's the issue. Although I can share the code files.
https://pastebin.com/3sx5W1u0     https://pastebin.com/JuKZRjGR

Comment: Okay, What do you mean by App is crashing? does it mean you try to open the app with location turned off and then you get the error?

Comment: can you share the Exception/Error logs?

Comment: I mean if i have app in background and i turn my app location permission off then if i open my app from background it crashes at that time only.
If i kill and open my app then it works fine.
Im not able to produce Exception/Error logs

Comment: It is bound to crash then. You are turning location permission off. You need to check the permission before starting the location listener.

Answer (score 0):

You could register for the LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION in the BroadcastReceiver. When it is hit, you can check if the provider is still enabled and use that accordingly to prevent your app from crashing when someone revokes the location permission.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = locationManager != null && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting

> I mean if i have app in background and i turn my app location
>   permission off then if i open my app from background it crashes at
>   that time only. If i kill and open my app then it works fine. Im not
>   able to produce Exception/Error logs

The behavior you are observing is correct. You need to explicitly check for the Location Permission before registering/starting location update listener.